# Setting a react hook to an array causing loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Has anyone else noticed this weird behavior?

It seems that when i declare a function that sets a hook to an array within the `useState` hook, I get a infinite loop.

But setting the same hook to an empty string does not cause a loop.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    FooFunction()
  },[foo]);

  function FooFunction () {
    // If you setFoo with an array we can an infinite loop
    setFoo('')
    // setFoo([1,2,3])
  }

  return <div className="App">Whats up with this loop?</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with being an array. `useEffect` callback calls `FooFunction`, which sets `foo`. `foo` is a dependency of `useEffect`, so it gets called again, and so on ad infinitum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are reference types. By setting `foo` to an array, you are creating a new reference. That means your dependency on `foo` in your `useEffect` changes. Any changes in your dependencies trigger a rerender of your component.

When you use `setFoo('')`, strings are compared by value (e.g. `'' === ''` is true) so your dependency doesn't change in that case.

Comment: He can use the Spread syntax and solve this problem, because when you send and let arr = [] and setFoo(...arr) it will not trigger again until he will do something like setFoo(...arr,1)

Comment: True, but I was just trying to explain why this is happening on a broader level.